# Issue in skipping an index while using enumerate to from a second list from an existing list

Tags: python, list

I have below sample `list` in `python`:

```
room_list = [['Room A','ok'],['Room B','ok'],['Room C','ok'],['Room D','ok'],['Room E','ok'],['Room F','ok'],['Room G','ok'],['Room H','ok'],['Room I','ok']]
```

I am trying to from another `list` from this `list` which is of `['%d. Room number: %s']` where `%d` is an increasing number and `%s` is the room number value from above list(the 1st item from each inner list). But what I want to do is to skip number `5` for `%d` and call it `6` - meaning Following should be the output of new list for above sample list:

```
new_room_list = ['1. Room number: Room A','2. Room number: Room B','3. Room number:  Room C','4. Room number: Room D','6. Room number: Room E','7. Room number: Room F','8. Room number: Room G','9. Room number: Room H','10. Room number: Room I']
```

As you can see I don't want to skip any data but just skip number `5` and call it `6`(in above output `Room E` should have been `5` but was named to `6`). I wrote this line for code but it doesn't skip number 5:

```
new_room_list = ["%d. Room number: %s" % (i,*(x[:-1])) for i, x in enumerate(room_list, 1)]
```

How is it possible to skip and rename `5` to `6`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new_room_list = ["%d. Room number: %s" % (i+1 if i > 4 else i,*(x[:-1])) for i, x in enumerate(room_list, 1)]
```

Output:

```
['1. Room number: Room A', '2. Room number: Room B', '3. Room number: Room C', '4. Room number: Room D', '6. Room number: Room E', '7. Room number: Room F', '8. Room number: Room G', '9. Room number: Room H', '10. Room number: Room I']
```

The only change I made was replacing `(i,*(x[:-1]))` with `(i+1 if i > 4 else i,*(x[:-1]))`

I used python's version of the ternary operator which is used as follows:

```
a if condition else b
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a custom iterator, `itertools` usually has something to help you solve this problem simply:

```
In [7]: from itertools import chain, count

In [8]: it = zip(chain(range(1, 5), count(6)), room_list)

In [9]: ['%d. Room number: %s'%(i, rm) for i, (rm,  _) in it]
Out[9]:
['1. Room number: Room A',
 '2. Room number: Room B',
 '3. Room number: Room C',
 '4. Room number: Room D',
 '6. Room number: Room E',
 '7. Room number: Room F',
 '8. Room number: Room G',
 '9. Room number: Room H',
 '10. Room number: Room I']
```

Careful, though, `chain(range(1, 6), count(7))` is an infinite iterator. `zip` stops when the shortest iterator stops, but if, for example, you used `itertools.zip_longest`, this would blow up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next`:

```
room_list = [['Room A','ok'],['Room B','ok'],['Room C','ok'],['Room D','ok'],['Room E','ok'],['Room F','ok'],['Room G','ok'],['Room H','ok'],['Room I','ok']]
l = iter(range(1, len(room_list)+2))
final_rooms = ["{}. Room number: {}".format(next(l) if i != 4 else [next(l), next(l)][0], a) for i, (a, _) in enumerate(room_list, start = 1)]
```

Output:

```
['1. Room number: Room A', '2. Room number: Room B', '3. Room number: Room C', '4. Room number: Room D', '6. Room number: Room E', '7. Room number: Room F', '8. Room number: Room G', '9. Room number: Room H', '10. Room number: Room I']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to visualize it; decompress the singleton you have and break it into its components. Make a normal appending for-loop, and re-create the singleton if you want it.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from pprint import PrettyPrinter

pp = PrettyPrinter(indent=2)

rooms_list = [
    ["Room A", "ok"],
    ["Room B", "ok"],
    ["Room C", "ok"],
    ["Room D", "ok"],
    ["Room E", "ok"],
    ["Room F", "ok"],
    ["Room G", "ok"],
    ["Room H", "ok"],
    ["Room I", "ok"]
]

print("Rooms Lists")
pp.pprint(rooms_list)


new_rooms_list = []

for (index, (room, status)) in enumerate(rooms_list):
    new_rooms_list.append("{}. Room number: {}".format(
        index if index < 5 else index + 1,
        room
    )
)


print("Formatted Rooms")
pp.pprint(new_rooms_list)
```

And the output is as follows:

```
Rooms Lists
[ ['Room A', 'ok'],
  ['Room B', 'ok'],
  ['Room C', 'ok'],
  ['Room D', 'ok'],
  ['Room E', 'ok'],
  ['Room F', 'ok'],
  ['Room G', 'ok'],
  ['Room H', 'ok'],
  ['Room I', 'ok']]
Formatted Rooms
[ '0. Room number: Room A',
  '1. Room number: Room B',
  '2. Room number: Room C',
  '3. Room number: Room D',
  '4. Room number: Room E',
  '6. Room number: Room F',
  '7. Room number: Room G',
  '8. Room number: Room H',
  '9. Room number: Room I']
```

Now, you can have that middle section back as a singleton / generator:

```
new_rooms_list = [
    ("{}. Room number: {}".format(
        index if index < 5 else index + 1,
        room
    )) for index, (room, status) in enumerate(rooms_list)
]
```